# Which statistical test you propose to assess whether there is significant effect of specified categorical variable (s) on a categorical outcome?

Tags: statistics, correlation, graphs, inference

I have a table that I am trying to analyse.

```
GAME    COMP win
BBall   N   Y
FBall   N   Y
FBall   N   Y
BBall   N   Y
FBall   Y   Y
FBall   N   Y
BBall   Y   Y
FBall   Y   N
BBall   N   Y
FBall   N   Y
```

John plays football and baseball under competitive and non-competitive conditions.
He wants to know which he is better at.

- What is a good statistical test to determine which game he is better at? I think Chi-Square test. Does that make sense?
- Are there some useful visual charts that can be used to show this?
- Also, an informative chart to show wins vary by game or competitiveness?

Comment: N Y denote No,Yes respectively. Is it true ? what is win column.

Comment: COMP= Competitive and its values are Y(Yes) and N (No). The Win column is the result of the game, if he won the game or not. On the win column, Y mins yes(win), N means no (he lost).